# Is After Effects object model available for testing outside of Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I am actually writing a script, which I prefer to test in my browser with Javascript tools such as Live Reload, Mocha.js and Google Chrome's inspector. Although, my browser legitimately returns me errors when I call app obect methods. Would there be a .js or .jsx file I could just include to be able to test it out of Adobe Extend Script Toolkit? Or is it kind of a secret file?

Comment: I'm guessing you could work something out with jslint but that's just to check syntax, not actually check if the script would do what you expect it to do in after effects. Perhaps the Object Model Viewer and auto-complete in Extend Script Toolkit can help a bit in getting the right arguments, but what you're aiming for sounds a bit tough

Answer (score 2):

You'll never get certain AE-, ExtendScript API-specific code to work in other ECMA hosts. You can see that even using the ExtendScript Toolkit, you (often, depending) need to specify your target app (toolkit, AE, Illustrator, etc.) because of differences across apps. Basic ECMA you can test using the methods described; for ExtendScript-specific code, you have to use the appropriate app (AE/Toolkit, etc.).